# Converter in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, converters

I Have a DataGrid and two columns inside.
First one: LimitType and 
Second one: is LimitValue.

For example:
First column: 0 - if Money type, 1 - if Percent Type
Second column should: in case of 0 in the first column show value in money format, otherwise in Percent format.

How can I format the second column in depending of First Column Value.
I tried to do it using Converter, but I can't pass as a parameter the value of the first column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solulution.

DataGridTextColumn should be binded to MultiplyBinding type for both values - from first column and second column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind the object itself in your DataGrid's column definition.

I'm thinking about something like that :

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource valueFormatConverter}}" />
```

but the simple Binding with no argument doesn't seem to be binding directly to the object as I would expect, so maybe use a trick and add a member to your class that references the object itself.

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DummyClass MySelf { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it in the binding :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding MySelf, Converter={StaticResource valueFormatConverter}}" />
```

Here is the converter :

```
public class ValueFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = (MainWindow.DummyClass)value;

        if (v.Type == 0)
        {
            return v.Value + " (Type 0)"; // Do your formatting here
        }
        else if (v.Type == 1)
        {
            return v.Value + " (Type 1)";  // Do your formatting here
        }
[...]
```